Techelet tallit katan and white talit gadol - which do I make a bracha on?
Assuming someone puts techelet on their talit katan, and regular white on their talit gadol.
Is it preferable to make a bracha on the talit gadol, and cover the talit katan (to avoid an unncessary bracha)? or is it preferable to make 2 brachot, so that the mitzva of techelet will receive its own blessing?

Why would it be better for a particular instance of the mitzvah to get its own blessing?

Maybe you should say the bracha on the tallis katan and cover the tallis gadol.

@Heshy lchatchila the blessing on a talit katan is "al mitzvat tzitzit", and the blessing on a talit gadol is "lehitatef". B'dieved it works, but is this a b'dieved situation?

@DoubleAA Take a look at MB OC 8 s'if katan 24 "...V'hachi Adif t'fei"... would MB agree in this case? that's essentially my question

I don't understand why it would be different. All the MB's reasons still apply. Why would it be better for a particular instance of the mitzvah to get its own blessing?

because each talit has a mitzvah advantage over the other.
